# Is Hodrick-Prescott filter optimal with irregular component?

Tags: econometrics, business-cycles

I need to extract cyclical component from time series, when doing seasonal adjustment I have the option to remove, apart from seasonal component, the irregular component. Then I'll apply HP to the resulting series, should I leave there or remove the irregular component?

Comment: I thought the irregular component was the noise left in the series after the trend, level and cyclical were removed ? Perhaps the terminology one of us is using is different ?

Comment: Just an aside, http://blog.eviews.com/2017/07/hamiltons-why-you-should-never-use.html